# Spring reactor - How to properly throw Exception?

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have this code:

```
   public void createImage(Image image) {
        tokenProvider.getAccessToken()
                .flatMap(accessToken -> restCllent.decodeColour(url, accessToken.getToken())
                    .flatMap(colour -> restClient.createImage(url, accessToken.getToken())))
                .subscribe();
  }
```

in the function decodeColour I have this code which call external service:

```
    public Mono<Colour> decodeColour(String path, String token) {
        log.info("Executing GET request to {}", path);
        return webClient
            .get()
            .uri(path)
            .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, String.format(TOKEN_BEARER, token))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Colour.class)
            .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Error occurred during colour decoding: " + e.getMessage())));
    }
```

When external service returns for example 401, I handled that in onErrorResume(),
and I want to just throw RuntimeException.
In the code above "createImage(Image image)" function, how I can force the code to just throw the RuntimeException if the error occurred in decodeColour()?
If I leave it like this, I get
ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: RuntimeException: Error occurred during colour decoding.
And if I add some error callback like doOnError, it just handle the error, but I want to program throws my RuntimeException. It is important to me to do that.

Comment: `ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: RuntimeException: Error occurred during colour decoding` this is a `RuntimeException` it says, RUNTIMEexception

Comment: Hi @ThomasAndolf, yes but I'm calling this function createImage() from Apache Camel, 
and with this exception ErrorCallbackNotImplemented, the Camel won't try to process the message again.
I don't want to get this ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: RuntimeException, but only to be RuntimeException: Error occurred during colour decoding.

Comment: `It is important to me to do that.` reactor does not work with `RuntimeException` what is it you actually want to do. Reactive doesnt throw RuntimeExceptions, webflux doesnt throw any exceptions.